# how to get the confidence interval of accumulative effect when using Difference-In-Difference

Tags: confidence-interval, causality, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

say i have a dataframe like below:

```
    post treat  y   item
    0   0   1   001
    0   0   2   001
    1   0   3   001
    1   0   4   001
    1   0   5   001
    0   1   2   001
    0   1   4   001
    1   1   6   001
    1   1   8   001
    1   1   10  001.
```

and when I run did like below:

```
print(smf.ols('y ~ treat*post ', data=df).fit().summary()).
```

I can get the average treatment effect and the confidence interval, e.g. [p - CI, p + CI].
this can be interpreted as average treatment effect for each item after the intervention( effect per item per day).
how can we get the accumulative effect for all items in all days after the intervention and its confidence interval?
the point estimate is simply p*num_of_items*num_of_days, but what about the confidence interval?